# Check if a user has privilege to start/stop/reboot ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to programatically stop, start and reboot my ec2 instances via the below methods

```
Ec2AsyncClient.stopInstances(..)
Ec2AsyncClient.startInstances(..)
Ec2AsyncClient.rebootInstances(..)
```

What is the right way to check if the user has privileges to perform these actions on the given ec2 instances?

Comment: check iam policy attached to user or you can try aws cli command with --dry run option to simulate API call but this is not so efficient

Comment: Outside of developers and sysadmins, most AWS users have limited or no IAM permissions so they can't query their own policies.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from executing the commands another way to check is AWS's **IAM Policy SImulator**:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html

[image]